# CameraX can't save image to gallery - "Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camerax

I'm trying to take a photo inside the app and save it to the gallery using CameraX.
The Manifest includes all the necessary permissions for camera and storage usage.
When I open the activity inside the app, the camera opens and all but when I try to take a photo I get these error messages and can't seem to figure out how to fix it. Any ideas?

This is my CameraActivity class:

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final int MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private final int MY_EXT_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    private TextureView view_finder;
    private Button closeCamBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

        view_finder = findViewById(R.id.view_finder);

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_EXT_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        else{
            startCamera();
        }

        // handling cancel-button from camera-activity
        closeCamBtn = findViewById(R.id.closeCam);
        closeCamBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> finish());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == MY_EXT_STORAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "write ext storage permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "write ext storage permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }


    // TODO always yields onError()

    private void startCamera() {
        CameraX.unbindAll();

        Rational aspectRatio = new Rational(view_finder.getWidth(), view_finder.getHeight());
        Size screen = new Size(view_finder.getWidth(), view_finder.getHeight());

        PreviewConfig pConfig = new PreviewConfig.Builder().setTargetAspectRatio(aspectRatio).setTargetResolution(screen).build();
        Preview preview = new Preview(pConfig);

        preview.setOnPreviewOutputUpdateListener(
                output -> {
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view_finder.getParent();
                    parent.removeView(view_finder);
                    parent.addView(view_finder);

                    view_finder.setSurfaceTexture(output.getSurfaceTexture());
                }
        );

        ImageCaptureConfig imageCaptureConfig = new ImageCaptureConfig.Builder().setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CaptureMode.MIN_LATENCY).
                setTargetRotation(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation()).build();

        final ImageCapture imgCap = new ImageCapture(imageCaptureConfig);

        findViewById(R.id.imgCapture).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
            File file = new File(path, "ThisIsATestFile" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File would be: " + file.getAbsolutePath(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            imgCap.takePicture(file, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onImageSaved(@NonNull File file) {
                    String msg = "Photo capture succeeded: " + file.getAbsolutePath();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull ImageCapture.UseCaseError useCaseError, @NonNull String message, @Nullable Throwable cause) {
                    String msg = "Photo capture failed: " + message;
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    if(cause != null) cause.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        });
        CameraX.bindToLifecycle(this, preview, imgCap);
    }
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
    D/Camera: issue capture request for camera 0
    D/CaptureSession: Issuing capture request.
    W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0
    W/ExifInterface: Skip the tag entry since data format (ULONG) is unexpected for tag: GPSAltitudeRef
    W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0
    W/ExifInterface: Stop reading file since a wrong offset may cause an infinite loop: 0
    W/System.err: java.io.IOException: Could not rename to /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ThisIsATestFile1674077498232.jpg.tmp
    W/System.err:     at androidx.exifinterface.media.ExifInterface.saveAttributes(ExifInterface.java:4307)
    W/System.err:     at androidx.camera.core.Exif.save(Exif.java:132)
    W/System.err:     at androidx.camera.core.ImageSaver.run(ImageSaver.java:91)
    W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

I'm kinda lost here

Comment: Interesting. It's likely that the device is doing something special in the EXIF tags that triggers a bug in ExifInterface. If you post the question to camerax-developers@android.com with the device model, they might be able to help you.

Comment: @J_R did you find a solution for this? I am getting the exact same error.